# Are the use cases for translating Java to XSD different than translating XSD to java using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have seen similar questions saying that the direction to take (java to xsd or xsd to java)  depends on your focus, in other words are you looking to create the perfect schema or perfect java design.

However I am curious to know if the use cases are the really same. A colleague of mind commented, "why would you want to go from java to xsd?", if you do that you have already created an implementation. Which sort of does beg the question, why would you start with hand written java, convert to xsd, and then eventually convert to generated java.

To try to ask it differently, does it really matter which route you take (java to xsd or xsd to java) , because in the end the artefact that you require is xsd, which can be converted adhoc to java when and if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each approach has its pros and cons:

**XML-To-Java:**

- PRO: The interface contract is a first class artifact.  It is explicitly designed and coded.  Expressing of constraints (e.g. number of times an element can/should appear) is directly and naturally supported by XSD.
- CON: Degree of difficulty.  In my experience, I have found that most professional Java developers tend not to be fluent in XML Schema.  Thus there can be a learning curve.

**Java-To-XML:**

- PRO: Fast, efficient development.  Look at the JAX-RS and JAX-WS specs (implemented in tools such as Apache CXF).  These APIs apply annotations to Java interfaces to produce web services.  The web service contracts (i.e. the WDSL/WADL in XSD) are auto-generated by the web service framework.  The advantage here is that Java developers can work entirely in Java.  No need to learn XSD.
- CON: Because the interface is generated, it is not a first-class artifact.  It cannot easily be shared with consumers of your service.  It also means that a Java developer could change part of the Java interface, and inadvertently change the service contract.  I have seen this happen.  A change to the structure of an object (which BTW is not even a method signature change) can alter the XSD.